# Compute the Cartesian Distance between points in high-dimensional space optimally

Tags: c#, optimization

**Summary:**

My class SquareDistance computes the square of the Cartesian distance in four ways using methods with these names:

1. Signed
2. UnsignedBranching
3. UnsignedDistribute
4. CastToSignedLong

The first one is fastest and uses signed integers, but my data must be unsigned (for reasons given below). The other three methods start with unsigned numbers. My goal is to write a method like those in SquareDistance that takes unsigned data and performs better than the three I already wrote, as close as possible in performance to #1. Code with benchmark results follows.  (unsafe code is permitted, if you think it will help.)

**Details:**

I am developing an algorithm to solve K-nearest neighbor problems using an index derived from the Hilbert curve. The execution time for the naive, linear scan algorithm grows in time quadratically with the number of points and linearly with the number of dimensions, and it spends all its time computing and comparing Cartesian distances.

The motivation behind the special Hilbert index is to reduce the number of times that the distance function is called. However, it must still be called millions of times, so I must make it as fast as possible. (It is the most frequently called function in the program. A recent failed attempt to optimize the distance function doubled the program execution time from seven minutes to fifteen minutes, so no, this is not a premature or superfluous optimization.)

**Dimensions**: The points may have anywhere from ten to five thousand dimensions.

**Constraints**. I have two annoying constraints:

1. The Hilbert transformation logic requires that the points be expressed as uint (unsigned integer) arrays. (The code was written by another, is magic and uses shifts, ANDs, ORs, and the like and can't be changed.) Storing my points as signed integers and incessantly casting them to uint arrays produced wretched performance, so I must at the very least store a uint array copy of each point.
2. To improve efficiency, I made a signed integer copy of each point to speed up the distance calculations. This worked very well, but once I get to about 3,000 dimensions, I run out of memory!

To save on memory, I removed the memoized signed integer arrays and tried to write an unsigned version of the distance calculation. My best results are 2.25 times worse than the signed integer version.

The benchmarks create 1000 random points of 1000 dimensions each and perform distance calculations between every point and every other point, for 1,000,000 comparisons. Since I only care about the relative distance, I save time by not performing the square root.

In debug mode:

> ```
> SignedBenchmark                  Ratio: 1.000 Seconds: 3.739
> UnsignedBranchingBenchmark       Ratio: 2.731 Seconds: 10.212
> UnsignedDistributeBenchmark      Ratio: 3.294 Seconds: 12.320
> CastToSignedLongBenchmark        Ratio: 3.265 Seconds: 12.211
> ```

In release mode:

```
 SignedBenchmark                  Ratio: 1.000 Seconds: 3.494
 UnsignedBranchingBenchmark       Ratio: 2.672 Seconds: 9.334
 UnsignedDistributeBenchmark      Ratio: 3.336 Seconds: 11.657
 CastToSignedLongBenchmark        Ratio: 3.471 Seconds: 12.127
```

The above benchmarks were run on a Dell with an Intel Core i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz with 16 GB memory. My larger algorithm already uses the Task Parallel library for larger tasks, so it is fruitless to parallelize this inner loop.

**Question:** Can anyone think of a faster algorithm than UnsignedBranching?

Below is my benchmark code.

**UPDATE**

This uses loop unrolling (thanks to @dasblinkenlight) and is 2.7 times faster:

```
public static long UnsignedLoopUnrolledBranching(uint[] x, uint[] y)
{
    var distance = 0UL;
    var leftovers = x.Length % 4;
    var dimensions = x.Length;
    var roundDimensions = dimensions - leftovers;

    for (var i = 0; i < roundDimensions; i += 4)
    {
        var x1 = x[i];
        var y1 = y[i];
        var x2 = x[i+1];
        var y2 = y[i+1];
        var x3 = x[i+2];
        var y3 = y[i+2];
        var x4 = x[i+3];
        var y4 = y[i+3];
        var delta1 = x1 > y1 ? x1 - y1 : y1 - x1;
        var delta2 = x2 > y2 ? x2 - y2 : y2 - x2;
        var delta3 = x3 > y3 ? x3 - y3 : y3 - x3;
        var delta4 = x4 > y4 ? x4 - y4 : y4 - x4;
        distance += delta1 * delta1 + delta2 * delta2 + delta3 * delta3 + delta4 * delta4;
    }
    for (var i = roundDimensions; i < dimensions; i++)
    {
        var xi = x[i];
        var yi = y[i];
        var delta = xi > yi ? xi - yi : yi - xi;
        distance += delta * delta;
    }
    return (long)distance;
}
```

**SquareDistance.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DistanceBenchmark
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provide several alternate methods for computing the square of the Cartesian distance
    /// to allow study of their relative performance.
    /// </summary>
    public static class SquareDistance
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the square of the Cartesian distance between two N-dimensional points
        /// with calculations done on signed numbers using signed arithmetic, 
        /// a single multiplication and no branching.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">First point.</param>
        /// <param name="y">Second point.</param>
        /// <returns>Square of the distance.</returns>
        public static long Signed(int[] x, int[] y)
        {
            var distance = 0L;
            var dimensions = x.Length;
            for (var i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
            {
                var delta = x[i] - y[i];
                distance += delta * delta;
            }
            return distance;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the square of the Cartesian distance between two N-dimensional points
        /// with calculations done on unsigned numbers using unsigned arithmetic, a single multiplication
        /// and a branching instruction (the ternary operator).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">First point.</param>
        /// <param name="y">Second point.</param>
        /// <returns>Square of the distance.</returns>
        public static long UnsignedBranching(uint[] x, uint[] y)
        {
            var distance = 0UL;
            var dimensions = x.Length;
            for (var i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
            {
                var xi = x[i];
                var yi = y[i];
                var delta = xi > yi ? xi - yi : yi - xi;
                distance += delta * delta;
            }
            return (long)distance;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the square of the Cartesian distance between two N-dimensional points
        /// with calculations done on unsigned numbers using unsigned arithmetic and the distributive law,
        /// which requires four multiplications and no branching.
        /// 
        /// To prevent overflow, the coordinates are cast to ulongs.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">First point.</param>
        /// <param name="y">Second point.</param>
        /// <returns>Square of the distance.</returns>
        public static long UnsignedDistribute(uint[] x, uint[] y)
        {
            var distance = 0UL;
            var dimensions = x.Length;
            for (var i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
            {
                ulong xi = x[i];
                ulong yi = y[i];
                distance += xi * xi + yi * yi - 2 * xi * yi;
            }
            return (long)distance;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the square of the Cartesian distance between two N-dimensional points
        /// with calculations done on unsigned numbers using signed arithmetic, 
        /// by first casting the values into longs.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">First point.</param>
        /// <param name="y">Second point.</param>
        /// <returns>Square of the distance.</returns>
        public static long CastToSignedLong(uint[] x, uint[] y)
        {
            var distance = 0L;
            var dimensions = x.Length;
            for (var i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
            {
                var delta = (long)x[i] - (long)y[i];
                distance += delta * delta;
            }
            return distance;
        }

    }
}
```

**RandomPointFactory.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DistanceBenchmark
{
    public static class RandomPointFactory
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get a random list of signed integer points with the given number of dimensions to use as test data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="recordCount">Number of points to get.</param>
        /// <param name="dimensions">Number of dimensions per point.</param>
        /// <returns>Signed integer test data.</returns>
        public static IList<int[]> GetSignedTestPoints(int recordCount, int dimensions)
        {
            var testData = new List<int[]>();
            var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            for (var iRecord = 0; iRecord < recordCount; iRecord++)
            {
                int[] point;
                testData.Add(point = new int[dimensions]);
                for (var d = 0; d < dimensions; d++)
                    point[d] = random.Next(100000);
            }
            return testData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a random list of unsigned integer points with the given number of dimensions to use as test data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="recordCount">Number of points to get.</param>
        /// <param name="dimensions">Number of dimensions per point.</param>
        /// <returns>Unsigned integer test data.</returns>
        public static IList<uint[]> GetUnsignedTestPoints(int recordCount, int dimensions)
        {
            var testData = new List<uint[]>();
            var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            for (var iRecord = 0; iRecord < recordCount; iRecord++)
            {
                uint[] point;
                testData.Add(point = new uint[dimensions]);
                for (var d = 0; d < dimensions; d++)
                    point[d] = (uint)random.Next(100000);
            }
            return testData;
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DistanceBenchmark
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static IList<int[]> SignedTestData = RandomPointFactory.GetSignedTestPoints(1000, 1000);
        private static IList<uint[]> UnsignedTestData = RandomPointFactory.GetUnsignedTestPoints(1000, 1000);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseline = TimeIt("SignedBenchmark", SignedBenchmark);
            TimeIt("UnsignedBranchingBenchmark", UnsignedBranchingBenchmark, baseline);
            TimeIt("UnsignedDistributeBenchmark", UnsignedDistributeBenchmark, baseline);
            TimeIt("CastToSignedLongBenchmark", CastToSignedLongBenchmark, baseline);
            TimeIt("SignedBenchmark", SignedBenchmark, baseline);
            Console.WriteLine("Done. Type any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void SignedBenchmark()
        {
            foreach(var p1 in SignedTestData)
                foreach (var p2 in SignedTestData)
                    SquareDistance.Signed(p1, p2);
        }

        public static void UnsignedBranchingBenchmark()
        {
            foreach (var p1 in UnsignedTestData)
                foreach (var p2 in UnsignedTestData)
                    SquareDistance.UnsignedBranching(p1, p2);
        }

        public static void UnsignedDistributeBenchmark()
        {
            foreach (var p1 in UnsignedTestData)
                foreach (var p2 in UnsignedTestData)
                    SquareDistance.UnsignedDistribute(p1, p2);
        }

        public static void CastToSignedLongBenchmark()
        {
            foreach (var p1 in UnsignedTestData)
                foreach (var p2 in UnsignedTestData)
                    SquareDistance.CastToSignedLong(p1, p2);
        }

        public static double TimeIt(String testName, Action benchmark, double baseline = 0.0)
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            benchmark();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            var seconds = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            var ratio = baseline <= 0 ? 1.0 : seconds/baseline;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-32} Ratio: {1:0.000} Seconds: {2:0.000}", testName, ratio, seconds));
            return seconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Code Review. Stack Overflow is for debugging code that does not work or produces the wrong result.

Comment: (1) Is there a preferred mechanism for moving questions to that other forum? I am only accustomed to using StackOverflow. (2) In my case, the poor speed of the program IS the wrong result. What is the best forum for improving code speed?

Comment: Try Code Review or Programmers. I think CR is a better fit. I am having trouble figuring what your problem is. What is fixed, what you want optimised etc.

Comment: I added a summary to clarify exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Try converting to floating-point and using your language's BLAS bindings.  All-pairs distances can be computed much better via matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to shave off a lot of execution time by [unrolling your loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling):

```
public static long Signed(int[] x, int[] y)
{
    var distance = 0L;
    var dimensions = x.Length;
    var stop = dimensions - (dimensions % 4);
    for (var i = 0; i < stop; i+=4)
    {
        var delta0 = x[i] - y[i];
        var delta1 = x[i+1] - y[i+1];
        var delta2 = x[i+2] - y[i+2];
        var delta3 = x[i+3] - y[i+3];
        distance += (delta0 * delta0)
                  + (delta1 * delta1)
                  + (delta2 * delta2)
                  + (delta3 * delta3);
    }
    for (var i = stop; i < dimensions; i++)
    {
        var delta = x[i] - y[i];
        distance += delta * delta;
    }
    return distance;
}
```

This change alone reduced the execution time from 8.325s to 4.745s on my local system - a 43% improvement!

The idea is to do four points at a time while you can, and then finish off the remaining points in a separate loop.

Comment: I forgot about loop unrolling. However, in your example, what about when x[i] < y[i]? The subtraction goes negative, and we are working with unsigned numbers. (That is why I needed the ternary operator in one of mine, because I had to ensure that delta is positive always.)

Comment: @PaulChernoch This is an optimization of your `Signed` method. Your other three methods can be optimized by unrolling in the same way. I suspect that .NET also vectorizes this, because the improvement in speed goes far beyond what I expected to see.

Comment: Silly me, I didn't notice it was the signed method you optimized. I will try this to see what I get.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You made a huge dependency chain a factor of four shorter.  You can probably split it into separate dependency chains for an even bigger speedup.

Comment: I tried your approach on one of my unsigned methods and it went from 2.7x to 1.05x the baseline time! Fabulous!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the hilbert curve you can try a z curve, i.e. a morton curve. Translate the dimensions to a binary and interleave it. Then sort it. You can verify the upper bounds with the mostsignificat bits. Hilbert curve in n-dimension uses a gray code maybe you can search the internet for a faster version. You can find some fast implementation in the hackers cookbook. A morton curve should be similar to a h-tree. When you need the precision you can try copies of the hilbert curves, i.e. a moore curve. For example in 2d you can interleave 4 hilbert curves:

[image]"
,

Comment: Interesting suggestion. However (1) I spent several months looking for a faster Hilbert transform or trying to write my own, leading to the one I chose, which does start with Gray codes and goes from there. (2) The locality properties of Hilbert Curves are much superior to Z-curves. (I read literature on Star discrepancy and bounding box density calculations, etc.) (3) The algorithm I use for Hilbert transforms also involves interleaving bits. Optimizing THAT was a royal pain, but I succeeded. (The interleave process was taking 55% of my program time at one point!)

Comment: @PaulChernoch:It's an approximation but I think its patented. Maybe you can try the moore curve? You need 2 different hilbert curve and you cab mirroring/caching the incomplete. The moore curve its also better then the hilbert curve but it depends on the data.

Comment: @PaulChernoch:Imo BIGMINT and LIMINT or so:http://www.google.com/patents/US8688723.

Comment: Thanks for the patent information! Fortunately a quick scan reveals that their method diverges significantly from mine, but it is good to know.

Comment: @PaulChernoch:If my answer is helpful please consider to vote! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Best possible improvement I can see isn't going to be a low hanging fruit. This kind of problem is not well suited for the current version of the .net framework (or a CPU in general).

The class of problem you have is called SIMD. You may have heard of Intel Pentium MMX. The MMX instruction set is the marketing term for SIMD instruction set.

There are three pretty good ways to get SIMD to run with your program. In order of slowest to fastest, and in order of easiest to hardest.

1. `RyuJIT` (the preview version of the next .net Compiler) to take advantage of CPU SIMD
2. `P/Invoke` into `C++ AMP` onto your GPU
3. Interop onto a FPGA with a core designed for this calculation.

I would highly recommend trying to take advantage of your GPU with C++ AMP, especially since `uint[]` should be easily passed to `C++ AMP`.

Comment: Wow.  Just...no.  MMX is one particular set of SIMD instructions from last century that's been entirely superseded by the SSE and AVX families.  SIMD just means "single instruction, multiple data"---it's a term for vector instructions.

Comment: Have you benchmarked point-to-point distance on a GPU and an FPGA, including the time spent shipping the data over and the result back, or are your points 2 and 3 just speculation?

Comment: @tmyklebu Single instruction, [Multiply–accumulate operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation), or as GPGPUer call it FMA (fused multiply accumulate).

Comment: @tmyklebu Hmm...just had a lot of fun with the `GPULinq` project. Unfortunately its not very good, as its currently synchronous. This makes each call pretty expensive. But each run scales well. Currently trying to work out how to run each run in parallel instead of in sequence...which is slow...

Comment: @tmyklebu BTW. If this is done asynchronously, what you mentioned is almost irrelevant. It's latency and not processing time.

Comment: @tmyklebu please go learn the difference between asynchronous and concurrent processing.

Answer (score 0):

In the shower this morning, I came up with a way to improve this further using the dot product, shaving another fifty percent off the time when the data is stored as uint[] arrays. I had investigated this idea before, but failed to recognize a loop invariant that I could optimize by precomputing. The basis of the idea is to distribute the operations:

```
    (x-y)(x-y) = x*x + y*y - 2xy
```

If I sum this over all coordinates, the result is:

```
        2         2       2
       D    =  |x|  +  |y|  -  2(x·y)
```

Since I will be performing lots of distance computations, I can store the square length of each vector. Then finding the distance between two vectors amounts to summing their square distances (outside the loop) and computing the dot-product, which has no negative values, so needs no branching!

Why is the branching a problem? It is because with uint vectors you can't subtract values in the Cartesian formula without using a branch operation to test which value is larger. Thus if I want (x-y)*(x-y) I needed to do this in my loop:

```
var delta = x[i] > y[i] ? x[i] - y[i] : y[i] - x[i];
distance += delta * delta;
```

In addition, to prevent overflow from uint to ulong, I needed to cast numbers to ulong a lot, which really killed performance. Since most of my coordinates are smallish, I was able to create a test. I also store the max value for each vector. Since I am unrolling my loops by four iterations at a time, if 4*xMax*yMax does not overflow uint, I can dispense with most of my casting operations. If the test fails, I do the more costly version that casts more.

In the end, I had several implementations: naive with casting, with branching, distributed with casting and loop invariants not removed, and dot product with less casting and invariants removed.

The naive approach has a subtraction, a multiplication and an addition in each loop iteration. The dot product distribution with loop invariants removed uses only a multiplication and an addition.

Here are the benchmarks:

```
For 100000 iterations and 2000 dimensions. 
    Naive time        = 2.505 sec. 
    Branch time       = 0.628 sec. 
    Distributed time  = 6.371 sec.
    Dot Product time  = 0.288 sec.
    Improve vs Naive  = 88.5%.
    Improve vs Branch = 54.14%.
```

Here is the code as an NUnit test:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Linq;

namespace HilbertTransformationTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class CartesianDistanceTests
    {

        [Test]
        public void SquareDistanceBenchmark()
        {
            var dims = 2000;
            var x = new uint[dims];
            var y = new uint[dims];
            var xMag2 = 0L;
            var yMag2 = 0L;

            for (var i = 0; i < dims; i++)
            {
                x[i] = (uint)i;
                xMag2 += x[i] * (long)x[i];
                y[i] = (uint)(10000 - i);
                yMag2 += y[i] * (long)y[i];
            }
            var xMax = (long)x.Max();
            var yMax = (long)y.Max();
            var repetitions = 100000;
            var naiveTime = Time(() => SquareDistanceNaive(x, y), repetitions);
            var distributeTime = Time(() => SquareDistanceDistributed(x, y), repetitions);
var branchTime = Time(() => SquareDistanceBranching(x, y), repetitions);
            var dotProductTime = Time(() => SquareDistanceDotProduct(x, y, xMag2, yMag2, xMax, yMax), repetitions);

            Console.Write($@"
For {repetitions} iterations and {dims} dimensions. 
    Naive time        = {naiveTime} sec. 
    Branch time       = {branchTime} sec. 
    Distributed time  = {distributeTime} sec.
    Dot Product time  = {dotProductTime} sec.
    Improve vs Naive  = {((int)(10000 * (naiveTime - dotProductTime) / naiveTime)) / 100.0}%.
    Improve vs Branch = {((int)(10000 * (branchTime - dotProductTime) / branchTime)) / 100.0}%.
");
            Assert.Less(dotProductTime, branchTime, "Dot product time should have been less than branch time");
        }

        private static double Time(Action action, int repeatCount)
        {
            var timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();
            for (var j = 0; j < repeatCount; j++)
                action();
            timer.Stop();
            return timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0;
        }

        private static long SquareDistanceNaive(uint[] x, uint[] y)
        {
            var squareDistance = 0L;
            for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                var delta = (long)x[i] - (long)y[i];
                squareDistance += delta * delta;
            }
            return squareDistance;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the square distance, using ternary operators for branching to keep subtraction operations from going negative,
        /// which is inappropriate for unsigned numbers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The distance branching.</returns>
        /// <param name="x">The x coordinate.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The y coordinate.</param>
        private static long SquareDistanceBranching(uint[] x, uint[] y)
        {
            long squareDistanceLoopUnrolled;

            // Unroll the loop partially to improve speed. (2.7x improvement!)
            var distance = 0UL;
            var leftovers = x.Length % 4;
            var dimensions = x.Length;
            var roundDimensions = dimensions - leftovers;

            for (var i = 0; i < roundDimensions; i += 4)
            {
                var x1 = x[i];
                var y1 = y[i];
                var x2 = x[i + 1];
                var y2 = y[i + 1];
                var x3 = x[i + 2];
                var y3 = y[i + 2];
                var x4 = x[i + 3];
                var y4 = y[i + 3];
                var delta1 = x1 > y1 ? x1 - y1 : y1 - x1;
                var delta2 = x2 > y2 ? x2 - y2 : y2 - x2;
                var delta3 = x3 > y3 ? x3 - y3 : y3 - x3;
                var delta4 = x4 > y4 ? x4 - y4 : y4 - x4;
                distance += delta1 * delta1 + delta2 * delta2 + delta3 * delta3 + delta4 * delta4;
            }
            for (var i = roundDimensions; i < dimensions; i++)
            {
                var xi = x[i];
                var yi = y[i];
                var delta = xi > yi ? xi - yi : yi - xi;
                distance += delta * delta;
            }
            squareDistanceLoopUnrolled = (long)distance;

            return squareDistanceLoopUnrolled;
        }

        private static long SquareDistanceDistributed(uint[] x, uint[] y)
        {
            long squareDistanceLoopUnrolled;

            // Unroll the loop partially to improve speed. (2.7x improvement!)
            var distance = 0UL;
            var dSubtract = 0UL;
            var leftovers = x.Length % 4;
            var dimensions = x.Length;
            var roundDimensions = dimensions - leftovers;

            for (var i = 0; i < roundDimensions; i += 4)
            {
                ulong x1 = x[i];
                ulong y1 = y[i];
                ulong x2 = x[i + 1];
                ulong y2 = y[i + 1];
                ulong x3 = x[i + 2];
                ulong y3 = y[i + 2];
                ulong x4 = x[i + 3];
                ulong y4 = y[i + 3];

                distance += x1 * x1 + y1 * y1 
                          + x2 * x2 + y2 * y2 
                          + x3 * x3 + y3 * y3 
                          + x4 * x4 + y4 * y4;
                dSubtract += x1 * y1 + x2 * y2 + x3 * y3 + x4 * y4;
            }
            distance = distance - 2UL * dSubtract;
            for (var i = roundDimensions; i < dimensions; i++)
            {
                var xi = x[i];
                var yi = y[i];
                var delta = xi > yi ? xi - yi : yi - xi;
                distance += delta * delta;
            }
            squareDistanceLoopUnrolled = (long)distance;

            return squareDistanceLoopUnrolled;
        }

        private static long SquareDistanceDotProduct(uint[] x, uint[] y, long xMag2, long yMag2, long xMax, long yMax)
        {
            const int unroll = 4;
            if (xMax * yMax * unroll < (long) uint.MaxValue)
                return SquareDistanceDotProductNoOverflow(x, y, xMag2, yMag2);

            // Unroll the loop partially to improve speed. (2.7x improvement!)
            var dotProduct = 0UL;
            var leftovers = x.Length % unroll;
            var dimensions = x.Length;
            var roundDimensions = dimensions - leftovers;

            for (var i = 0; i < roundDimensions; i += unroll)
            {
                var x1 = x[i];
                ulong y1 = y[i];
                var x2 = x[i + 1];
                ulong y2 = y[i + 1];
                var x3 = x[i + 2];
                ulong y3 = y[i + 2];
                var x4 = x[i + 3];
                ulong y4 = y[i + 3];
                dotProduct += x1 * y1 + x2 * y2 + x3 * y3 + x4 * y4;
            }
            for (var i = roundDimensions; i < dimensions; i++)
                dotProduct += x[i] * (ulong)y[i];
            return xMag2 + yMag2 - 2L * (long)dotProduct;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the square of the Cartesian distance using the dotproduct method,
        /// assuming that calculations wont overflow uint.
        /// 
        /// This permits us to skip some widening conversions to ulong, making the computation faster.
        /// 
        /// Algorithm:
        /// 
        ///    2         2       2
        ///   D    =  |x|  +  |y|  -  2(x·y)
        /// 
        /// Using the dot product of x and y and precomputed values for the square magnitudes of x and y
        /// permits us to use two operations (multiply and add) instead of three (subtract, multiply and add)
        /// in the main loop, saving one third of the time.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The square distance.</returns>
        /// <param name="x">First point.</param>
        /// <param name="y">Second point.</param>
        /// <param name="xMag2">Distance from x to the origin, squared.</param>
        /// <param name="yMag2">Distance from y to the origin, squared.</param>
        private static long SquareDistanceDotProductNoOverflow(uint[] x, uint[] y, long xMag2, long yMag2)
        {
            // Unroll the loop partially to improve speed. (2.7x improvement!)
            const int unroll = 4;
            var dotProduct = 0UL;
            var leftovers = x.Length % unroll;
            var dimensions = x.Length;
            var roundDimensions = dimensions - leftovers;
            for (var i = 0; i < roundDimensions; i += unroll)
                dotProduct += (x[i] * y[i] + x[i+1] * y[i+1] + x[i+2] * y[i+2] + x[i+3] * y[i+3]);
            for (var i = roundDimensions; i < dimensions; i++)
                dotProduct += x[i] * y[i];
            return xMag2 + yMag2 - 2L * (long)dotProduct;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I am leaving the "official" answer with @dasblinkenlight, since it the most generally useful to most people and I used his suggestion of loop unrolling as part of mine. It cut more time off than my extra innovation did, so was the most important of the optimizations.